# cloud project iis express 8 Static compression is being disabled

Tags: azure, iis-express

Here's my setup:

- An MVC web project that is hosted in azure
- VS2012 and VS2013
- Windows Azure SDK 2.2
- IIS Express 8 - 8.0.1557

The MVC project is using castle windsor, and there are performance counters being created during application start up.

When I run the project locally (via emulator) I am find that during the performance counters creation an exception is being thrown however the performance counters are created and copied across to azure table storage.

Exception:

```
The directory specified for caching compressed content C:\Users\danielc\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\c2fd1c9b-d6c5-49af-942d-715c8f1ccc1c\temp\temp\RoleTemp\iisexpress\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\767ba5ae-0038-4c32-a70c-3d2f671e37ed is invalid.  Static compression is being disabled.
```

When I try and find this location, it does not exist, which implies to be that it maybe a permission issue, but I dont know how to change the permissions for the emulator.

To add to my headache, I am in a team of 6, all of which are not experiencing this issue. Furthermore when it is deployed to azure it works fine as well.

My question therefore is, has anyone experienced this issue before and know a solution?

Steps taken so far:

- Uninstall and install azure sdk 2.2
- Install azure sdk 2.3
- Install azure sdk 2.4
- Uninstall and install IIS Express 8
- Uninstall IIS Express 8 and install IIS Express 7.5 (which turned out did work as not supported but just clutching at straws really)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe I have got to the bottom of it. It would appear the  instance count in the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg is 4, but when set to 1 it runs fine.

It is very odd that my colleagues who work with this other configuration are not experiencing the issue.